# Why is itext not filling fields?

Tags: pdf, itext, scribus

We have some Scribus files with empty text fields that we export as pdf and then fill the fields with itext. Having upgraded to Scribus 1.5.5 and itextpdf 5.5.13.1 (from lowagie) a couple of the files that previously worked no longer display any inserted text. Stepping through the code that uses itext seems entirely normal and works fine for most files. Any hints as to what might cause such behavior or how to debug it?

Comment: As the issue only occurs for some pdfs, we very likely will need an example file to analyze.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v-K3TKoaSIltWL8qDF0fiD-gswAOawq9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'd also need the file after iText attempts to fill it in to see what went wrong.

Comment: One observation, though: That file has the **NeedAppearances** flag set to **true**. That means that PDF *viewers* have to re-generate the appearances of the fields when loading the file. Thus, *intermediary* PDF processors like your iText form fill-in don't need to generate and store appearances, they merely need to store the value. iText at some time in the 5.x versions, therefore, stopped generating the appearances. Unfortunately, though, some viewers don't do what they are expected to and don't re-generate appearances. Which PDF viewer do you use?